# Stream tar.gz file from FTP server

Tags: ftp, shell-scripting, wget

Here is the situation: I have a **tar.gz** file on a FTP server which can contain an arbitrary number of files.

Now what I'm trying to accomplish is have this file streamed and uploaded to HDFS through a Hadoop job. The fact that it's Hadoop is not important, in the end what I need to do is write some shell script that would take this file form ftp with `wget` and write the output to a stream.

The reason why I really need to use streams is that there will be a large number of these files, and each file will be huge.

It's fairly easy to do if I have a gzipped file and I'm doing something like this:

```
wget -O - "ftp://${user}:${pass}@${host}/$file" | zcat
```

But I'm not even sure if this is possible for a **tar.gz** file, especially since there are mutliple files in the archive. I'm a bit confused on what direction to take for this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
wget -O - "ftp://${user}:${pass}@${host}/$file" | tar xfz -
```